# How can we retrieve "Case Status" picklist values marked as "Closed" in setup?

Tags: apex, case

I've marked multiple Case Status picklist values as "Closed", and now I want to access only those picklist values which are marked as Closed in Apex class. I tried looking for this in documentation but could not find any thing.

[image: I need to find "picklist" values which are marked here as Closed]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update:

You need to query a standard salesforce object [CaseStatus](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_casestatus.htm):

> This object represents a value in the case status picklist.  Query the
>   CaseStatus object to retrieve the set of values in the case status
>   picklist.

```
Select Id, MasterLabel From CaseStatus Where IsClosed = true
```

---

<s>You nees to use this field "Status" in your SOQL query:</s>

```
List<Case> cases = [select Id from case where status='Closed'];
System.debug('#### cases: ' + cases);
```

Comment: No that will not work. I don't need Cases list but need list of Picklist Values that have been marked as 'Closed' as shown in this screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/W0GroPoih

Comment: @VarunChaddha Ahh, got you now. Updated my answer.

Comment: thnx a bunch :-) ...