# Group by: Combining two groups

Tags: soql, query, group-by

I need help with this query. It returns me with 3 groups: Closed, Waiting and In progress. However I want to combine the Waiting and In progress groups to see the Closed vs not closed. How can I do this, this is the query I have now.

```
select Status,count(CaseNumber) number from Case where Quelle__c = 'Nutzer' and 
(CreatedDate = THIS_QUARTER or ClosedDate = THIS_QUARTER) GROUP BY Status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use Apex code:

```
Integer notClosed = 0;
Integer closed = 0;
for (AggregateResult ar : [...]) {
    String s = (String) ar.get('Status');
    Integer n = (Integer) ar.get('number');
    if (s != 'Closed') {
         notClosed += n;
    } else {
         closed += n;
    }
}
```

**PS**

Also there is also the IsClosed field on Case:

```
select IsClosed, count(Id) number from Case group by IsClosed
```

and you can configure the statuses this corresponds to in the [status field setup](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24621/how-can-we-retrieve-case-status-picklist-values-marked-as-closed-in-setup).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is just not what I am looking for. I really need it in SOQL.

Comment: @Martijn See the **PS**.

Comment: That did it. Thank you. 1 more thing, is there any way I can name the groups? So it wont say True / Unknown.

Comment: @Martijn You could add a formula field based on `IsClosed` to `Case` containing a friendlier name and group by that.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that. But thank you!

Comment: @Martijn While you can add the formula, it turns out you then can't group by it - see [Allow SOQL GROUP BY on formula fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HlNtAAK) so you need to use workflow or a trigger to set the value that depends on IsClosed n a normal custom text field.